# Randomly choose index based on condition in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have 2D numpy array with 0 and 1 as values. I want to randomly pick an index that contains 1. Is there efficient way to do this using `numpy`?

I achieved it in pure python, but it's too slow.

Example input:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

output:

```
(0, 1)
```

EDIT:
For clarification: I want my function to get 2D numpy array with values belonging to {0, 1}. I want the output to be a tuple (2D index) of randomly (uniformly) picked value from the given array that is equal to 1.

EDIT2:
Using Paul H's suggestion, I came up with this:

```
    nonzero = np.nonzero(a)
    return random.choice(list(zip(nonzero)))
```

But it doesn't work with numpy's random choice, only with python's. Is there a way to optimise it better?

Comment: _I achieved it in pure python_. Always include your code. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. Only plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: use `numpy.random.choice` and `numpy.nonzero`

Comment: The question is too broad / leave lots of room for interpretation. Please clarify the exact requirement(s).

Comment: Is my clarification sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to get all the non-zero coordinates and sample from there:

```
xs,ys = np.where([[0, 1], [1, 0]])

# randomly pick a number:
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(xs)) )

# output:
out = xs[idx], ys[idx]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot faster than mine

Answer (score 1):

You may try `argwhere` and `permutation`

```
a = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])

b = np.argwhere(a)
tuple(np.random.permutation(b)[0])
```